# AS3 - SimpleFTP client uploads 0 byte file to Filezilla Server

Tags: actionscript-3, ftp

I am trying to upload a file my filezilla server using SimpleFTP https://github.com/kohyama/SimpleFTP

Here is my code:

```
var ftp_client:SimpleFTP = new SimpleFTP("127.0.0.1", "USER", "user1");

var test22:String = "Hello World!";

public function main():void
{
    trace("Attempting to upload a file on: 127.0.0.1 ...");
    connect_test_upload();
}

private function connect_test_upload():void
{
    ftp_client.SimpleFTP.putFile("127.0.0.1", "USER", "user1", "\hello.txt", test22, function(res:String):void{});
    trace("Success!");
}
```

I was like OMG IT WORKED but actually the file was 0 bytes. (AKA a derp file)
There is no errors in the Filezilla server console.
Please help! D:

Answer (score 0):

You should consider doing what the page you linked to suggests:

> To check if your session succeeded or not, check if `res.substr(0,3) == "226"`, otherwise `SimpleFTP.get()` calls your `handler` with `res` the response from FTP server which is not equal to the expected. If `res.substr(0,3) == "226"`, contents should saved as the file you specified.

Comment: Ok there are no errors... (I checked if it equals 226 and it does) Weird.. still 0 bytes